# Creating new Mat variable crashes android app

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio, image-processing

I am working on a vision targeting system that uses openCV in part of the code. One of the steps involves using Mats. I have created a new mat using `Mat newMat = Mat()` and `Mat newMat = Mat(2, 2, CvType.CV_8UC3)` and a few other Cv types. No matter what I try, when I run the code, as soon as it gets to the aforementioned line, the app completely crashes. The stack trace reports one of two things. When the longer form of a mat declaration is used (2nd code snippet) it looks like this:

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcontroller.internal.FtcRobotControllerActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.qualcomm.analytics.Analytics@f31dd7d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                  android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcontroller.internal.FtcRobotControllerActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.qualcomm.analytics.Analytics@f31dd7d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:918)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:719)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1172)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1152)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1146)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                      at com.qualcomm.analytics.Analytics.register(SourceFile:209)
                      at com.qualcomm.analytics.Analytics.<init>(SourceFile:235)
                      at com.qualcomm.modernrobotics.ModernRoboticsUsbUtil.init(SourceFile:85)
                      at com.qualcomm.ftccommon.FtcEventLoop.init(FtcEventLoop.java:191)
                      at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.EventLoopManager.startEventLoop(EventLoopManager.java:571)
                      at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.EventLoopManager.setEventLoop(EventLoopManager.java:545)
                      at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.EventLoopManager.start(EventLoopManager.java:489)
                      at com.qualcomm.robotcore.robot.Robot.start(Robot.java:59)
                      at com.qualcomm.ftccommon.FtcRobotControllerService$RobotSetupRunnable$1.run(FtcRobotControllerService.java:186)
                      at com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.ThreadPool.logThreadLifeCycle(ThreadPool.java:513)
                      at com.qualcomm.ftccommon.FtcRobotControllerService$RobotSetupRunnable.run(FtcRobotControllerService.java:128)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

But should I use the shorter form (1st code snippet) I get this as well as the the content of the 1st stack trace

```
E/art: No implementation found for void org.opencv.core.Mat.n_delete(long) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete__J)
E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.opencv.core.Mat.n_delete(long) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete__J)
              at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_delete(Native Method)
              at org.opencv.core.Mat.finalize(Mat.java:911)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Is there a simple explanation about why the code is causing a crash? In the code I am running right now, the only lines are the class declaration, the function declaration, and the mat declaration, yet that appears to be all it takes.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that a few lines of code in the main activity where missing. They load the openCV library and if it is not present, they use the openCV library app.

This goes in OnCreate

```
if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
          RobotLog.d("OpenCV", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for Initialization");
          OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mOpenCVCallBack);
      }else{
          RobotLog.d("OpenCV", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
          mOpenCVCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
      }
  }
```

and this goes right below the declaration of the main activity class:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {


        @Override
          public void onManagerConnected(int status){
              switch (status){
                  case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                  {
                      RobotLog.i(TAG, "OpenCV Loaded Sucessfully");
                  }break;
                  default:
                  {
                      super.onManagerConnected(status);
                  }break;
              }
          }
      };
```

Comment: Thanks you, This is the correct answer, but how could you figure it out?!!! documentation on android is very weak.